# How to get type of specific "keyof" parameter in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'd like to define an Adapter Schema, to convert one Object into another.

```
export type AdapterSchema<Source, Destination> = {
    [key in keyof Partial<Source>]: {
        target: keyof Destination;
        convert: (source: Source[key]) => Destination[keyof Destination];
    };
};
```

It should be possible to add a convert function, that converts the value of a property into the value of the target property.

```
interface Foo {
   a : string;
}

interface Bar {
   b : number;
   c : string;
}

const schema : AdapterSchema<Foo,Bar> = { a : {target: 'b', convert: (value) => 'x'}}
```

I want the compiler to throw an error here, because 'x' is not of type number. My type is at least a bit type safe, because only types of Bar are allowed, but no error is thrown, because Bar has also a property of type string.

Can this be made more type safe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to change `AdapterSchema<S, D>` so that each property is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the different possible `target`/`convert` pairs for *each* key `KD` in the `D` type.

That is, whatever `AdapterSchema<S, D>` is, you want `AdapterSchema<Foo, Bar>` to evaluate to:

```
type ASFB = AdapterSchema<Foo, Bar>;
/* type ASFB = {
    a?: {
        target: "b";
        convert: (source: string) => number;
    } | {
        target: "c";
        convert: (source: string) => string;
    } | undefined;
} */
```

We can do this by changing your version (slightly rewritten but it's the same):

```
type OrigAdapterSchema<S, D> = {
    [KS in keyof S]?: {
        target: keyof D;
        convert: (source: S[KS]) => D[keyof D];
    };
};
```

to the following version:

```
type AdapterSchema<S, D> = {
    [KS in keyof S]?: ({ [KD in keyof D]-?: {
        target: KD;
        convert: (source: S[KS]) => D[KD];
    } }[keyof D]);
}
```

This works by building a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where each key `KD` of `D` is given a property where `target` is `KD` and where `convert`'s return type is `D[KD]`... and then immediately [indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into it with `keyof D` to get the union of properties.

You can verify that now `AdapterSchema<Foo, Bar>` is the desired type.  And now the compiler behaves as you wanted:

```
const badSchema: AdapterSchema<Foo, Bar> = {
    a: { target: 'b', convert: (value) => 'x' } // error!
    //   ~~~~~~ <-- b is not assignable to c
}

const schema: AdapterSchema<Foo, Bar> = {
    a: {
        target: "b",
        convert: v => v.length
    }
}; // okay
```

(Note that this solution does *not* force`AdapterSchema<S, D>` to really produce every property in `D`; for example `{}` is an acceptable `AdapterSchema<Foo, Bar>`, or you could have each property in `S` map to the same property in `D`.  But your question is not about this, so any answers to this are out of scope here.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgSwOYEEAmBDMwJwMoDGAFhALYYA8eANFACIB8UAvFAN4BQU3UA2gNJ4oCAHZQA1hBAB7AGZQ8AXQD8ALnZceW4BjhIIwdZJny6Abk1buBaSIBuuQ1AAUAZ2kBXOAQjq8ApQBKFiY6XmM5ekULLQBfC3iODlBIKHQsHHxiMkoaeiZWTi0A4TEI+SU1FzY+fjpSiSlIukUAWiqiq24dPQN1OpiuqBt7R3U3T29fBQDFYOZQgRbB7lioWPCm0zmEpI5RTNkMHygAMWlpDS0MdVdgRBEkXf2RQ+PoACFdK54AI3URB5SL9cCthrd7qInhxYnsUtAUHhTh8WGlMNhcIQSOQKOdpLQvnAGBYAPQAKig8LSSJRhUsUAwHXp2l0+icACJfuywVoRg44E4Jl4fBCHkh5kxAcDQfS1gAfH5dHps9Tsgjc5k8PljFzuYXTO5iiVQQ1QsHyqAeERoCCyUQQNAJKBkkl7EZ3KC-DBoLE5dTpDFZbGUPEE3QFRUM9Q1ZV9KAAcl+8do2oF4zsGAANh4IMb4wAPePrKAkklQXBwaRwACE9NLPAAfk3m1AKK1Wp7hK4oCJpMAGa5XMgRBhfpnoMBLgQYUl3f3XNlyP70ZlfTjQ1BCRHOtwbpGWb0OVzqJrrLZ+U47CEoHYAHTjx7AIiymFmEtl6TiDAgIA)

Comment: That's awesome! I ended up using: 

type AdapterSchema<S, D> = {
    [KS in keyof S]?:
        | {
              [KD in keyof D]?: {
                  target: KD;
                  convert: (source: S[KS]) => D[KD];
              };
          }[keyof D]
        | keyof D;
};

and it works like a charm! Thank you!